# IMAP Library for fetching new mails

Tags: c#, imap

I need to read mails from Mail Server via IMAP and store in DB. My question is

1. How i can know which mails are already stored in DB and which are now. Based on timestamp? But in that case I have to loop through all the mails and get the timestamp. I dont want to loop through or get all the mails because the mailbox will be huge.

What approach should i take? 
Should i forward new mails to a temp account - read from that account and then delete that mail?

Please let me know ASAP

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is do you need to retain those emails on the IMAP server? or can you simply delete them after the download?

All IMAP servers assign a special Unique ID (uid) to each email as it arrives in the mailbox.
Uids are assigned in **incremental order**. In case of most servers those uids are also stable across sessions, and never change.

This means that to know what emails are new you just need to **remember the last uid you downloaded** previously.

For reading emails you'll need an [IMAP library](http://www.limilabs.com/mail), I recomend this one: http://www.limilabs.com/mail, but please note that I was involved in the development and it is a commercial product.

Here's the article that shows how to [get new emails from the server](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/get-new-emails-using-imap) and the [details on unique id in IMAP](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/unique-id-in-imap-protocol)

Comment: I am building library for IMAP my search command works file for the Inbox folder it returns me a number which i can use to fetch the mail. However when i try to search on Sent Items it doesnot work it doesnot give an error but just returns Search OK without any numbers. Can you please point out why this behavior. I am hitting Exchange 2010.

my search command is something like search all HEADER Message-ID ""

This is exactly how it is described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302965

But i cannot find a resolution. Please help its very urgent.

Thanks